# How to fetch all possible pattern in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have below table:

```
+----------+----+
|customerID|name|
+----------+----+
|         1| Ram|
+----------+----+
```

I want output as (All possible value of column-value):

```
+----------+----+
|customerID|name|
+----------+----+
|         1| Ram|
|         2| Arm|
|         3| Mar|
|         .| ...|
|         .| ...|
+----------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Split string, explode array and use cross join with itself to find all possible combinations:

```
 with s as (select col 
              from (select explode( split(lower('Ram'),'')) as col)s 
             where col <>''
           ) 
 select concat(upper(s1.col), s2.col, s3.col) as name, 
        row_number() over() as customerId
   from s s1 
        cross join s s2 
        cross join s s3
where s1.col<>s2.col and s2.col<>s3.col;
```

Result:

```
OK
name    customerid
Mam     1
Mar     2
Mrm     3
Mra     4
Ama     5
Amr     6
Arm     7
Ara     8
Rma     9
Rmr     10
Ram     11
Rar     12
Time taken: 185.638 seconds, Fetched: 12 row(s)
```

Without last `WHERE s1.col<>s2.col and s2.col<>s3.col` you will get all combinations like `Aaa`, `Arr`, `Rrr`, etc.