# How to generate n-grams in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

How to generate n-grams in Hive?

i just know 1-gram is

```
select split("abcd", "|")
```

the output is ["a","b","c","d",""]

i know [How to generate all n-grams in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782188/how-to-generate-all-n-grams-in-hive) can do n-gram with words. But i want to do n-gram with string which only contains 'a'-'z' without space or comma

e.g.
input string "abcde"

output 2-gram: ["ab, "bc", "cd", "de"]

Comment: Read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52782188/2700344 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47210604/2700344

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.